# In google spreadsheets while using conditional formating can I colour a cell based on the values in cells left and right from it?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

[image]
In the image you can see that there are values in the row 1 and in column A. I change the  values in column and check the checkmarks. Based on those values I want to colour the calls in the area B2:G9. For every call in the range(E.g B2) if the value in the calumn A left from it(E.g A2) is higher than the value in the row 1 on top from it(E.g B1) of that cell then I want to colour it(E.g B2).

Can I achieve this with one rule or do I need to make a rule for every cell? What range do I chose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select range `B2:G9` and use custom rule:

```
=$A2>B$1
```

Result:

[image]